# Cpp - Check if key exist in boost bimap

Tags: c++, boost, bimap

I have a bimap. I want to check if key exists in my bimap. How can i do that. Here is my bimap:

```
namespace bimap
            {

                struct Name{};
                struct ID{};

                typedef
                    boost::bimaps::bimap<
                        boost::bimaps::set_of< 
                            boost::bimaps::tagged<
                                unsigned short
                                , ID
                            >
                        >,

                        boost::bimaps::set_of<
                                boost::bimaps::tagged<
                                std::string
                                , Name
                            >
                        >
                    >
                    name_index_bimap;
            }
```

I want to check if 'Name' is exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained quite clearly in [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/bimaps_with_user_defined_names.html). In your case, it should look like this:

```
name_index_map your_map;
name_index_map::right_const_iterator it = your_map.by<Name>().find("some name");
if(it == your_map.right.end()) {
    // name does not exists
}
```

Comment: The `find()` function belongs to the collection type used when defining the map type. In this example, it's `set_of`, which is documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/reference/set_of_reference.html).